# Find solution of differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of differential equation

> $$y''+8y'+17y=f(t), \\ y(0)=0, \\y'(0)=0,$$ where f(t) is the periodic function
>
> $$f(t)=1 
> , 0<t<\pi \\
> f(t)=0
>  , \pi<t<2\pi \\
>  f(t+2\pi)=f(t)
> $$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTY3M.jpg

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+8y'+17y=f(t), \\ y(0)=0, \\y'(0)=0,$$

You can use the Laplace Transform
$$\mathcal{L}\{y''+8y'+17y \}=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} $$
$$s^2Y(s)+8sY(s)+17Y(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} $$
$$Y(s)(s^2+8s+17)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} $$
For the Laplace Transform on RHS we get:
$$f_1(t)=1(u_t-u_{\pi})=u(t)-u(t-\pi)$$
$$\mathcal{L}\{f_1(t)\}=\frac 1 s -\dfrac {e^{-\pi s}}s$$
Since the period of $f(t)$ is $2 \pi$:
$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\left (\frac 1 s -\dfrac {e^{-\pi s}}s\right) \dfrac 1 {1-e^{-2\pi s}}$$
$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\left (\dfrac {1-e^{-\pi s}}{s(1-e^{-2\pi s})}\right) $$